# Return a version of the given array where each zero value in the array is replaced by the largest odd value to the right of the zero in the array

Tags: java, arrays

If there is no odd value to the right of the zero, leave the zero as a zero.

```
zeroMax([0, 5, 0, 3]) → [5, 5, 3, 3]
zeroMax([0, 4, 0, 3]) → [3, 4, 3, 3]
```

This is from CodingBat: https://codingbat.com/prob/p187050

There are certainly better implementations than mine, but it would help me tremendously to see where I went wrong.

It is the findAndReplace method that is not doing its job. I don't see a reason as to why it insists that intarray[0] = 0, and that is where I am stuck. I have implemented the method separately from this class, and it works as expected.

Below is my work:

```java
public class ZeroMax {
    public static int[] zeroMax(int[] intarray) {
        int max = largestOdd(intarray);
        System.out.println("largest odd is " + max);
        
        return findAndReplace1(intarray, 0, max);
    }

    //method returns the largest odd value or returns zero
    public static int largestOdd(int[] arr) {
        int maxodd = 0;
        int n = arr.length;
        int temp = 0;

        //this is just a bubble sort
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                    //swap elements
                    temp = arr[j - 1];
                    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        //this finds the largest number that is an odd
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
                maxodd = arr[i];
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return maxodd;
    }

    //following returns an array where the zeros (int find)
    // can be replaced with the largest odd (int replace)
    public static int[] findAndReplace1(int[] intarray, int find, int replace) {
        for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println(intarray[i]);
            if (intarray[i] == find) {
                intarray[i] = replace;
            }
        }
        return intarray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the key to your problem is

> … to the right of the zero in the array

One given example is zeroMax([0, 5, 0, 3]) → [5, 5, 3, 3]. In your code you are finding the greatest odd value *in the entire array*. 5 in this case. Then you are replacing every 0 in the array with 5.

```
Original array:  [0, 5, 0, 3]
Expected result: [5, 5, 3, 3]
Your result:     [5, 5, 5, 3]
```

So it seems that you still have a bit of coding to do.

> There are certainly better implementations than mine, …

Your implementation, your design and code style, are just fine. Only except for the lamentable fact that it didn’t solve the problem correctly.

**An idea how to solve the problem.** The following should work in all cases:

1. Iterate backward from the end array until the first (so the rightmost) odd number.
2. If there isn’t any odd number in the array, you’re done.
3. Store the odd number into a variable holding the greatest odd number encountered so far.
4. Continue iterating backward from the index you came to down to index 0. For each index:

   1. If the number at the index is odd and greater than the hitherto greatest odd number, store the number as the greatest odd number.
   2. If the number is 0, store the greatest odd number until now into the array at this index.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the question wrong. This is the successful solution that I came up with after more careful reading:

```java
public int[] zeroMax(int[] intarray) {
    int maxvalue = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++) {
        if (intarray[i] == 0) {
            index = i;
            //call max value method
            maxvalue = maxvalue(intarray, index);
            intarray[i] = maxvalue;
        }
    }
    return intarray;
}

public int maxvalue(int[] intarray, int index) {
    int maxvalue = 0;

    for (int i = index; i < intarray.length; i++) {
        if ((intarray[i] % 2 == 1) && (intarray[i] > maxvalue)) {
            maxvalue = intarray[i];
        }
    }
    return maxvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Arrays.stream(T[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-int-int-) method to iterate over this array from the current index to the end, then [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) odd numbers and get [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--) of them:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {0, 5, 0, 3};
    int[] arr2 = {0, 4, 0, 3};
    int[] arr3 = {0, 3, 0, 4};

    replaceZeros(arr1);
    replaceZeros(arr2);
    replaceZeros(arr3);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [5, 5, 3, 3]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [3, 4, 3, 3]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3)); // [3, 3, 0, 4]
}
```

```java
private static void replaceZeros(int[] arr) {
    // iterate over the indices of array
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            // filter zero elements
            .filter(i -> arr[i] == 0)
            // for each zero iterate over the elements
            // of array from the current index to the end
            .forEach(i -> Arrays.stream(arr, i, arr.length)
                    // filter odd elements
                    .filter(e -> e % 2 != 0)
                    // take the max element and
                    // replace the current one
                    .max().ifPresent(e -> arr[i] = e));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

- We want to replace every 0 with the highest odd number on its right hand side
- So we iterate from the end of the array and keep track of the maximum odd number that has appeared till that point
- Now whenever we encounter a 0, we will replace 0 with that max value
- Set the initial max value as 0 because in case we won't find an odd number our code will replace it with 0 only

Time Complexity:

- O(n)
- As we are going through the array only once

Space Complexity:

- O(1)
- As we have created only one variable max

JAVA CODE:

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {
  int n = nums.length;
  int i=n-1;
  int m=0;
  while(i>=0){
    if(nums[i]==0){
      nums[i]=m;
    }else if(nums[i]%2==1){
      m=Math.max(m,nums[i]);
    }
    i--;
  }
  return nums;
}
```